# Как пишется слово "положение"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как пишется слово "положение"? Понятно, что с заглавной буквы, когда оно является частью официального названия документа. А как быть в других случаях?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в других-то случаях зачем заглавная? Не вижу причин. 
Впрочем, приведите всю фразу, если есть сомнения.

===
"Это предусмотрено положениями о структурных подразделениях."

Понял. Здесь не надо. Если только раньше по тексту у вас нет фразы типа "далее именуемые Положениями".
Если бы это был один документ и нужно было подчеркнуть, что приводится его точное название, то можно с заглавной, но в кавычках. Это предусмотрено "Положением об Отделе внутренней охраны", например.

Answer (score 0):

"Это предусмотрено положениями о структурных подразделениях".

Comment: Понял. Здесь не надо. Если только раньше по тексту у вас нет фразы типа "далее именуемые Положениями".  
Если бы это был один документ и нужно было подчеркнуть, что приводится его точно название, то можно с заглавной, но в кавычках. *Это предусмотрено "Положением об Отделе внутренней охраны"*, например.